# How do I truncate this result?

Tags: php

this displays the name of a group, but sometimes the names of the groups are really long and break the layout. How can I limit the result to maybe 20 characters? Thank you!

```
<a href="<?php echo $group->getPermalink();?>" class="group-title"><?php echo $group->getName();?></a>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the [string functions](http://php.net/strings) (specifically the [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a php function for it. It's [substr()](https://php.net/substr). Your example code would look like:

```
<?php $length = 20; ?>
<a href="<?php echo $group->getPermalink();?>" class="group-title"><?php echo substr($group->getName(), 0, $length);?></a>
```

If you want, you can add some extra features like check the length and if it's longer than $length than cut it and add "..." for users to know, the text was cut.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work. Sorry this question seems to have annoyed some of you, but I want others to know how I fixed it.

```
    <a href="<?php echo $group->getPermalink();?>" class="group-title"><?php echo substr($group->getName(),0,25);?></a>
```